# How to delete GitHub repository connection from Brackets?

Tags: github, repository, adobe-brackets

For control version I use Github and I have a problem I can't solve.

I'm using Git plugin for Brackets and I want to desconnect a repository without deleting the directory file. I have been looking for a old question like this but I have not found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from the command line.

```
cd /Path/To/Directory
rm -rf .git/
```

That should remove the directory as a git repository.

Comment: Those lines deletes a GitHub repository? Or delete the connection between my directory and the repository?

Comment: Do you want to delete the repository from github or make the directory no longer a git repository?

Comment: I want the second one

Comment: The second one is what this does. Deleting the `.git` subdirectory uninitializes the repo and makes the directory just a regular directory.

Comment: Thank you so much!